# Why isn't this data inserted in my dictionary?

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

In this project to learn Python, I'm trying to save to my computer images from an Instagram account. The catch is that I want to only save the pictures if they're "high quality". My criteria to determine the quality of an image is the likes to followers ratio.

After days of trial and error, I managed to get some of my code working, except for filtering the likes to followers ratio.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe")

post_links = []
selection = {}

def acceptCookies():
    ##accept cookies
    cookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]")
    time.sleep(1)
    cookies.click()
    time.sleep(2)


def getPostLinks():
    ##Get url of the 5 most recent posts
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/earthpix/'
    browser.get(url)
    acceptCookies()
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span')
    followers = element.get_attribute('title')
    followers = followers.replace(' ', '')
    post = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/'
    links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
    for link in links:
        if post in link and link not in post_links:
            post_links.append(link)
            length = len(post_links)
            if length == 5:
                break
    time.sleep(10)
    for link in post_links:
        browser.get(link)
        try:
            phdiv = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img')
            photo = phdiv.get_attribute('src')
            selection["photo_url"] = photo
            time.sleep(1)
            likes = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('likes').text
            likes = likes.replace(' ', '')
            global ratio
            ratio = int(likes)/int(followers)*100
            selection["ratio"] = ratio
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            continue
        time.sleep(3)
    print(selection)

getPostLinks()
```

The code above returns my "selection" dictionary's value for the photo_url key but the ratio doesn't get added to the dictionary.

What could be causing this?

Comment: The first thing to check is if your `try` is covering up errors. You should really never have a bare `except:`, and `try`s should usually not wrap that much code. Specify the exact error to catch, and only wrap code that you expect to throw. An error is probably being thrown before `selection["ratio"] = ratio` is reached.

Comment: So, what you observe is that only part of a `try` block is executed? And you don't know what is going on, because... the `except` catches any exception, and ignores it? Maybe you should try *not doing that*, so you can see what exception was raised and why. Anyway, my guess: have you considered what happens if an image has zero followers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the fact that you are trying to get the number of likes by using `find_element_by_partial_link_text()` and Selenium is not finding it. Because of this, it always returns an exception and it doesn't assigns an ratio to the image.

To solve that, you should probably continue to use xpath to find the number of likes. The code will then look like that:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe")

post_links = []
selection = {}

def acceptCookies():
    ##accept cookies
    cookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]")
    time.sleep(1)
    cookies.click()
    time.sleep(2)


def getPostLinks():
    ##Get url of the 5 most recent posts
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/earthpix/'
    browser.get(url)
    acceptCookies()
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span')
    followers = element.get_attribute('title')
    followers = followers.replace(' ', '')
    post = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/'
    links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
    for link in links:
        if post in link and link not in post_links:
            post_links.append(link)
            length = len(post_links)
            if length == 5:
                break
    time.sleep(10)
    for link in post_links:
        browser.get(link)
        try:
            phdiv = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img')
            photo = phdiv.get_attribute('src')
            selection["photo_url"] = photo
            time.sleep(1)
            likes = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/button/span").text
            likes = likes.replace(' ', '').replace(",", "")
            global ratio
            ratio = int(likes)/int(followers.replace(",", ""))*100
            selection["ratio"] = ratio
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            continue
        time.sleep(3)
    print(selection)
    browser.quit()

getPostLinks()
```

Notice that I had to remove the commas. I had to do that because Instagram inserts a comma in the number of likes to make it more readable.

Another thing I should mention is that your function `acceptCookies` didn't work for me. Maybe it's because I was using Firefox, I don't know. But, anyway, I could run the code without it.

Answer (score 1):

A dict is a key-value.
One key = 1 value.
In your code, you always use the same key (photo_url and ratio) for each link.
I would rather try to return a list of dictionnaries objects, rather than a single dictionnary.
Like this:

- Note that I do not use global variables
- Note that I return a list (all_selections) of dictionnary objects (mysel)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe")

def acceptCookies():
    ##accept cookies
    cookies = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]")
    time.sleep(1)
    cookies.click()
    time.sleep(2)

def getPostLinks():
    post_links = []
    all_selections = []
    ##Get url of the 5 most recent posts
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/earthpix/'
    browser.get(url)
    acceptCookies()
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span')
    followers = element.get_attribute('title')
    followers = followers.replace(' ', '')
    post = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/'
    links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
    for link in links:
        if post in link and link not in post_links:
            post_links.append(link)
            length = len(post_links)
            if length == 5:
                break
    time.sleep(10)
    for link in post_links:
        browser.get(link)
        try:
            myselc = {}
            phdiv = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img')
            photo = phdiv.get_attribute('src')
            mysel["photo_url"] = photo
            time.sleep(1)
            likes = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('likes').text
            likes = likes.replace(' ', '')
            global ratio
            ratio = int(likes)/int(followers)*100
            mysel["ratio"] = ratio
            all_selections.append(mysel)
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            continue
    time.sleep(3)
    return all_selections
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to map the photo url to its ratio - isnt it?

```
...
time.sleep(1)
likes = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('likes').text
likes = likes.replace(' ', '')
global ratio
ratio = int(likes) / int(followers) * 100
selection[photo] = ratio
...
```